# If text contains a value of 2017 or higher set variable equal to a specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code where it checks the date and if the date is 2017 or newer the variable B is set to 100 000 otherwise if the date is 2016 or older B is set to 25000. Here is what I have so far but doesn't quite meet my needs.

```
   Do Until Y = ""
    'Do until run out of identifier values - reach blank cell in column
    Z = ARng2.Value
    'Z = Identifier Value
    Y = ARng2.Offset(i, 0).Value
    DateString = ARng2.Offset(i, -1)
    If InStr(DateString, "2017") > 0 Then
    B = Sheets("Information Sheet").Range("C7").Value
'100000
    Else
    B = Sheets("Information Sheet").Range("C6").Value
'25000
    End If
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Range C7 is set to 100000 and Range C6 is set to 25000 sorry I should have made note of that

Comment: What is your code doing that is not correct

Comment: It only checks if the date is 2017, I need it to check for 2017 or newer. So if the date is 2017 and newer set B = 100000 otherwise if the date is 2016 or older set B = 25000

Comment: What is the format of your dateString?

Comment: Its 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS' for example "2000-12-19 13-07-00" and I have it dimmed as a string

Comment: Do the cells contain *actual Date Values* or only text that *looks like* date values?

Comment: take the left 4 characters of your datestring and convert it to a number.  then comparer it to 2017 and see if it is greater than or equal to with your IF statment.

Comment: Like `B = 25000 - (ARng2.Offset(i, -1).Value >= 42736) * 75000` ???

Comment: also `B = 100000 * 4 ^ (ARng2.Offset(i, -1).Value < 42736)` is possible... (if you want to do it with math) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Year` function against a `Date` value, and then test it thusly:

```
If VBA.Year(ARng2.Offset(i, -1).Value2) >= 2017 Then
    B = Sheets("Information Sheet").Range("C7").Value
Else
    B = Sheets("Information Sheet").Range("C6").Value
End If
```

If `ARng2.Offset(i, -1)` contains a string literal, you may need to explicitly cast it to a date, like:

```
If VBA.Year(CDate(ARng2.Offset(i, -1).Value2)) >= 2017 Then...
```